# What does "가가가가가." (the sentence) mean?

Tags: grammar, korean-culture

I heard tale of a sentence which is odd but grammatically correct where every word is 가, but each 가 is a different part of speech.  I'm also not sure if it's five or six 가s, but I would love to reconnect with this doozy.

### Sentence: 가가가가가.

I'm pretty sure I know the first two

> 가 (Mr. Ga)
>
> 가 (subject particle)
>
> 가 (place ?)
>
> 가 (verb for "goes")

I think I'm missing at least one if not two more of them...

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently there are a bunch of these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3Lyxk7znRg) - based on 경상도 dialect.

The first one in that video, **가가가가**:

> 가 - equivalent of conventional '걔', "that person" 
>  가 - subject
>   particle 
>  가 - equivalent of conventional '걔', "that person" 
>   가? - a question ending, similar to '니?'

This means "is that person that person?", to be understood as (e.g.) "Is that the person you were talking about?

The second one is similar, but replaces the third '가' with

가 - (Surname 'Ga')
가 - equivalent of '씨', meaning 'Mr' (this is actually 家 - '집가').

Giving us:

> **가가가가가** 
>   "Is that person Mr. Ga?"

Comment: You should space after subject markers: `가가 가가?`, `가가 가가가?`. And note that the dialect is somewhat tonal, making it possible to distinguish them.

Comment: The YouTube video you linked has gone private!